# Integrating stripe subscription in php api

Tags: php, jquery, stripe-payments

I would like to integrate stripe subscription type payment in my website, Please help me to integrate this using stripe.js OR normal php based coding. I have good knowledge in php and jquery. I have already created the plans in the dashboard, I have stripe public & private key for testing.

Comment: The [docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api?lang=php) have all of the information that you need.

Comment: I know about the document, But they not providing any step by step procedure for any type of payment integration.

Comment: They do [here](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/guides/php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found best tutorial/article to integrate subscription type payment with stripe. I have integrated stripe in my website using this tutorial. Anyone can contact me for a help in this topic.

https://pippinsplugins.com/stripe-integration-part-7-creating-and-storing-customers/

https://pippinsplugins.com/stripe-integration-part-6-payment-receipts/